# SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN error when installing bower components

Tags: ember.js, bower, ember-cli, bower-install

Error while installing bower components, the following error is thrown

```
Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ember failed: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may get this error if your are behind a proxy or secure connection

Goto project root folder and open **.bowerrc**
 file and add the line

`"strict-ssl": false`

Example **.bowerrc** file

```
{

    "directory": "bower_components",
    "analytics": false,
    "strict-ssl": false
}
```

and from the project root folder do a bower install as follows

```
bower install
```